# Having trouble checking an array

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm supposed to search through a character array for another character array. The problem that I'm having is that I am supposed to check if the words match as well. Also, I keep getting an out of bounds exception when the search term is longer than the original string.

The `charArray` is the array of the search term.
The `indexArray` is the char array of the original string.

```
public int indexOf(String parameter) { //does same thing as previous method but with a String instead
    int index = -1;
    char charArray[] = parameter.toCharArray();
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < indexArray.length; i++) { //goes through the array and find which array element is = to the char

        if (indexArray[i] == charArray[0]) { //checks if the index is equal to the first AND second letter of the word

            for (int j = i; j < charArray.length; j++) {
                if (indexArray[j] == charArray[j]) {// this is where the Exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 14 error happens
                    counter++;
                }

                if (counter == charArray.length) {
                    index = i;
                    return index;
                }

            }
        }


    }
    return index;
}
```

Comment: Post stacktrace of.exception, and strings wich throws exception

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 14

Comment: Full stacktrace and which line it references.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 14
 at MyString.indexOf(MyString.java:53)
 at MyString.startsWith(MyString.java:74)
 at MainAssignment7.searchString(MainAssignment7.java:108)
 at MainAssignment7.main(MainAssignment7.java:70)

Answer (score 1):

Say if the indexArray is "grape" and charArray is "pineapple". At `i = 3`, `indexArray[i] == charArray[0]` returns true. Now you set `j = 3` and check until `j < 9`, and obviously `indexArray[j]` will give you an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You should change it to:

```
// There is no point to check indices that the subsequent string is shorter than the search string.
for (int i = 0; i < indexArray.length - charArray.length; i++) { 
    if (indexArray[i] == charArray[0]) {
        for (int j = 0; j < charArray.length; j++) {
            if (indexArray[i + j] == charArray[j]) {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```